# How do I retrieve high and low-order parts of a value from two registers in inline assembly?

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, g++, inline-assembly

I'm currently working on a little game that can run from the boot sector of a hard drive, just for something fun to do. This means my program runs in 16-bit real mode, and I have my compiler flags set up to emit pure i386 code. I'm writing the game in C++, but I do need a lot of inline assembly to talk to the BIOS via interrupt calls. Some of these calls return a 32-bit integer, but stored in two 16-bit registers. Currently I'm doing the following to get my number out of the assembly:

```cpp
auto getTicks = [](){
    uint16_t ticksL{ 0 }, ticksH{ 0 };
    asm volatile("int $0x1a" : "=c"(ticksH), "=d"(ticksL) : "a"(0x0));
    return static_cast<uint32_t>( (ticksH << 16) | ticksL );
};
```

This is a lambda function I use to call [this interrupt function](http://vitaly_filatov.tripod.com/ng/asm/asm_029.1.html) which returns a tick count. I'm aware that there are better methods to get time data, and that I haven't implemented a check for `AL` to see if midnight has passed, but that's another topic.

As you can see, I have to use two 16-bit values, get the register values separately, then combine them into a 32-bit number the way you see at the return statement.

Is there any way I could retrieve that data into a single 32-bit number in my code right away avoid the shift and bitwise-or? I know that those 16-bit registers I'm accessing are really just the higher and lower 16-bits of a 32-bit register in reality, but I have no idea how to access the original 32-bit register as a whole.

Comment: `CX` and `DX` are the low 16 bits of different registers, to put those together into a 32 bit register you will need to do some twiddling such as the shift and `or`. Since you used C code, just let the compiler figure out the best way to create code for that.

Comment: Oh, those are different registers, I see. I thought they were the higher and lower 16-bits of the same register, that's why I thought I could get this to work in a more efficient manner. If those are in fact different registers, I'm afraid I can't avoid these operations

Comment: The top 16 bits are not accessible directly.

Comment: So this is pretty much the best I can do, right?

Comment: I found [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture) in the meanwhile. This would have been helpful before I asked the question :) Anyway, add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it @Jester

Comment: Ehh... using GCC to generate 16-bit real-mode code is hack. Writing a whole game in C++ likely going to run into fundamental limitations like only having 64K of code and data and the need to port the GNU C/C++ runtime library.  You might look at using DJGPP, which runs 32-bit code under a DOS extender.

Comment: @RossRidge That is not the case. My program does not require any runtime library, as it's only using the core language, or even if I do use some standard library features, I make sure that all of those can be used in a `constexpr` function, so they emit no code into the final binary. I've already written programs that do simple graphical animations on the screen in C++ that result in a 150-byte or so binary, and they do work just fine when copied into the boot sector :)

Comment: @RossRidge I highly recommend [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBkNBP00wJE). It's about programming a game for a Commodore 64 in C++ 17. This was what inspired me to do something like this, but since I don't own a C64, I decided to write something that runs on x86 from a boot sector. That is a wonderful talk showing that even pretty high-level C++ abstractions can be compiled away to very tiny binaries with no library dependencies whatsoever.

Comment: Various core language features require runtime library support, the most obvious being the `new` operator. Less obvious are things like 64-bit integer arithmetic and global constructors. The more your code grows the more likely you're going to find that things don't just work fine.

Comment: Sure, there are things that need an underlying OS and a runtime library, but my code is pretty simple, so it won't really use any of that. All the data I'm using will be embedded in the binary, the I/O functions and graphics functions I need are written using inline assembly, and the rest is just very simple game logic built on top of those, so I sould be good. The whole point of my project is really to try to optimize C++ code to the smallest possible binary at the end. I'm doing it because I'm interested in things like this, not for the actual game really.

Comment: Unfortunately GCC doesn't provide space efficient 16-bit code generation since it is forced to use operand and address prefixes to over ride the default 16-bit. This can actually add a lot of unnecessary bytes if you are constrained to the remaining area in the 512 byte master boot record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that those 16-bit registers I'm accessing are really just the higher and lower 16-bits of a 32-bit register in reality, but I have no idea how to access the original 32-bit register as a whole.

As Jester has already pointed out, these are in fact 2 separate registers, so there is no way to retrieve "the original 32-bit register."

One other point: That interrupt modifies the ax register (returning the 'past midnight' flag), however your asm doesn't inform gcc that you are changing ax.  Might I suggest something like this:

```
asm volatile("int $0x1a" : "=c"(ticksH), "=d"(ticksL), "=a"(midnight) : "a"(0x0));
```

Note that `midnight` is also a uint16_t.

Comment: You could use `"+a"(midnight)` constraint for input/output and just set the midnight variable to 0 before the assembler template.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers suggest you can't load DX and CX directly into a 32-bit register. You'd have to combine them as you suggest.

---

In this case there is an alternative. Rather than using [*INT 1Ah/AH=0h*](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2271.htm) you can read the [BIOS Data Area (BDA)](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/bios_data_area.html) in low memory for the 32-bit DWORD value and load it into a 32-bit register. This is allowed in real mode on i386 processors. Two memory addresses of interest:

> ```
> 40:6C dword   Daily timer counter, equal to zero at midnight;
>               incremented by INT 8; read/set by INT 1A
> 40:70 byte    Clock rollover flag, set when 40:6C exceeds 24hrs
> ```

These two memory addresses are in [segment:offset](http://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/debug/Segments.html) format, but would be equivalent to physical address 0x0046C and 0x00470.

All you'd have to do is temporarily set the *DS* register to 0 (saving the previous value), turn off interrupts with *CLI* retrieve the values from lower memory using C/C++ pointers, re-enable interrupts with *STI* and restore *DS* to the previously saved value. This of course is added overhead in the boot sector compared to using *INT 1Ah/AH=0h* but would allow you direct access to the memory addresses the BIOS is reading/writing on your behalf.

Note: If *DS* is set to zero already no need to save/set/restore it. Since we don't see the code that sets up the environment before calling into the *C++* code I don't know what your default segment values are. If you don't need to retrieve both the roll over and timer values and only wish to get them individually you can eliminate the *CLI*/*STI*.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I was reading [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=WKaekAHjQ1EC&pg=PA345&lpg=PA345&dq=read+time+from+bios+data+area+cli&source=bl&ots=A2RR15gn4f&sig=wznVw6ygHSTr8O_LPln6wQ6B4bc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR-Ozi6NTQAhVS_mMKHenRCsoQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=read%20time%20from%20bios%20data%20area%20cli&f=false) (scroll down to the paragraph about "THE REAL-TIME CLOCK") that you had to watch for updates to status byte A to find out when it was safe to read.  Presumably using cli can slow down the clock?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd : This method doesn't actually query the hardware clock. The 2 values I mentioned are actually updated by the default BIOS Int 8h (IRQ0) handler. IRQ0 interrupt handler may access the real time clock hardware though, but the BIOS makes these 2 values available after processing. If you were to query the RTC through the data ports then you have to worry about timing.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the 'A' constraint, which refers to the dx:ax register pair as a double-wide value.  You can see the full set of defined constraints for x86 [in the gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html).  Unfortunately there are no constraints for any other register pairs, so you have to get them as two values and reassemble them with shift and or, like you describe.

Comment: My data is in `CX` and `DX`, not the ones that the "A" constraint refers to, so yeah, it seems like I do need to put those together at runtime.